# Upgrading from jQuery 1.3.2 to jQuery 1.5 (or 1.4)

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

I remember when jQuery 1.4 came out, there was a upgrade link and text where it said that there where stuff that was changed, and stuff we had to rewrite for it to work in 1.4.

I can't find this link anymore, because I now want to upgrade to 1.5 from 1.3.2 but I want to be sure everything still works.

Does anybody know of the differences and have a link I can use to upgrade correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The differences between 1.3.2 are listed here: http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14

And the release notes for 1.5: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/

The 1.4 link has a list of breaking changes, including a link to [this plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-compat-1.3) to counteract the breaking changes.

And now 1.6 as well: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to be needed for our office!

Answer (score 0):

Here the link: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/

Comment: This isn't the link I am looking for. I want the `how to upgrade from 1.3 guide`

Comment: ah sorry, but it's a good start to know what's new in this new release

Answer (score 0):

For anyone "these days" that is needing help with this, as I just did, it seems that the jQuery team created a better jQuery Migrate plugin that will allow some of the old deprecated code to still work in newer versions (1.9+) of jQuery. As well, if you get the uncompressed version of it, you can use it to pinpoint and debug your older code against the newer version. Works great, so I hope it helps someone else out!

[Compressed version of jQuery Migrate plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js)

[Uncompressed version of jQuery Migrate plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js)

I had some really old 1.3.2 code that stopped working when I upgraded to 1.10+, and this allowed it to continue to work without any issues, meanwhile also allowing me to pinpoint the exact code that I needed to rewrite.