# Will my site break if i migrate/upgrade jQuery 1.3 to 1.5?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-1.5, jquery-1.3

Currently i am using jQuery 1.3.2. i would like to migrate/upgrade the same to jQuery 1.5?

I am using some of the plugging as well. How can i make sure that it wouldn't break.
I don't where it would break if upgrade to jQuery 1.5. Please let me know your comments on this.

Comment: will you please provide link of your webpage or your jQuery code??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading from jQuery 1.3.2 to jQuery 1.5 (or 1.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960126/upgrading-from-jquery-1-3-2-to-jquery-1-5-or-1-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it shall break because lots of changes are been done between these upgrades.

Solution:

1. Upgrade all the plugins
2. upgrade the jQuery library to 1.6 (which is latest and all the plugins must be compatible with it).
3. Check every function that you have used [jQuery 1.4](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4/), [jQuery 1.5](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/), [jQuery 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/).

Then eventually verify the site at TEST server.

This is the only full proof way to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run your website locally or on a staging server?  The ideal scenario is you run a local/staged version of your website with the newer version of jQuery, and then thoroughly test it and fix any bugs that you find before applying the update to the live version of the site.

As to whether or not upgrading will cause things to break, my experience says that the answer is probably.