# How can I make this JQuery 1.3.2 code compatible with jQuery 1.6.2?

Tags: jquery

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
    $buildingup = false;

    $("#sliders>*").show();

    //Blurs all links when clicked
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).blur();
    });

    $(this).delay(2000,function(){
        $("#titlebar").fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $(this).delay(3500,function(){
        //Show the elements
        $(".village").stop().animate({top:'30px'}, {queue:false, duration:2000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
        $(".cloudbar").stop().animate({top:'0px'}, {queue:false, duration:2000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
        $buildingup = true;
    });

    $("a.toggle").click(function(){
        if ($buildingup == false){

            $("#titlebar").fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).delay(1000,function(){
                $(".village").stop().animate({top:'30px'}, {queue:false, duration:2000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
                $(".cloudbar").stop().animate({top:'0px'}, {queue:false, duration:2000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
                $buildingup = true;
            });
        }else{
            $(".village").stop().animate({top:'366px'}, {queue:false, duration:2000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
            $(".cloudbar").stop().animate({top:'-465px'}, {queue:false, duration:2000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
            $buildingup = false;

            $(this).delay(2000,function(){
                $("#titlebar").fadeIn(1000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: none of it. the titlebar div is supposed to fade out and then the village and cloudbar begin their animation but this does not work wen i use 1.6.2

Comment: For one, `delay` is not to be used as a replacement for `setTimeout`. This is a fairly simple substitution to make. http://api.jquery.com/delay

Comment: are you able to give a live example of it not working? Just looking at this code isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Have you even tried debugging your own code? Are there any errors?

Comment: Why don't you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

> The differences between 1.3.2 are listed here:
>   http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14
>
> And the release notes for 1.5:
>   http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/
>
> The 1.4 link has a list of breaking changes, including a link to this
>   plugin to counteract the breaking changes.
>
> And now 1.6 as well:
>   http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

[Upgrading from jQuery 1.3.2 to jQuery 1.5 (or 1.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960126/upgrading-from-jquery-1-3-2-to-jquery-1-5-or-1-4)